# data files automatically changing to read only

Tags: readonly

Any file that I intend to open using Pandas, either with Spider or with jupyter notebook, I am unable to open as its showing a unicode error. Upon inspecting, I realize, the file which I open is automatically changing to read-only. How can I remove this error?

This file is not a read only file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOpoR.png)

Upon opening it in spider or jupyter notebook, its showing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qpcn.png)

The error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqfzA.png)

with slight modification on codes [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj80R.png)

It shows: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN2sv.png)

Upon inspecting original file again, it is changing to read-only [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEmH1.png)